# multi word in full text index search - sql

Tags: sql

I have this stored proc the do fulltext index search with INFLECTIONAL support.
The code below seems to have problem with two words throws error message.

No error

```
INNER JOIN  CONTAINSTABLE (ProductRequest, (Abstract , Cause , Description ), 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,''emailaddress'') OR ''windowsproduct''' ) AS KEY_TBL
```

Syntax Error

```
//Note the white space in email address
INNER JOIN  CONTAINSTABLE (Table2, (Abstract , Cause , Description ), 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,''email address'') OR ''windowsproduct''' ) AS KEY_TBL
//Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
//Syntax error near 'ddress'' in the full-text search condition 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,'emaila ddress') OR 'windowsproduct''.

//Note the white space at the end of email address
INNER JOIN  CONTAINSTABLE (Table2, (Abstract , Cause , Description ), 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,''emailaddress '') OR ''windowsproduct''' ) AS KEY_TBL
//Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
//Syntax error near ''' in the full-text search condition 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,'emailaddress ') OR 'windowsproduct''.
```

Can someone show me the correct syntax?

Comment: I found the answer. use double quote ( " ) in keyword instead of single quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search a phrase you must use double quotes, but you are using two single quotes instead.
Try this:

```
INNER JOIN  CONTAINSTABLE (ProductRequest, 
 (Abstract , Cause , Description ), 
 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"email address") OR "windowsproduct"' ) AS KEY_TBL
```